# Access 2013 Compile error - object required

Tags: vba, ms-access-2013

I use Access quite a bit but only dabble in VBA code. I have some code that works, but I tried to compile the code and get the following error.

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
Dim RS As Date
Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblDate")
MsgBox ("The month and year are: " & RS)
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "LP Completions", "PDFFormat(*.pdf)", Chr(34) & "\\sharepoint.xx.yyyy.zzz\Reports\" & Format(RS.Fields(0), "yyyy-mm") & Chr(32) & " - LP Completions - Exec Report.pdf" & Chr(34), False
End Sub
```

I get a Compile Error: Object Required. In the code view the **RS =** is highlighted.

I have no clue why this is coming up. Can someone provide some guidance as to how to fix this? Thanks so much!

Comment: Also, if I google your exact question title the first hit I get explains exactly that.

Comment: I googled it as well and saw the entry you mention. When I remove Set I then get another error. Compile Error: Type Mismatch.

Comment: Ok, sorry. However you went one step backwards when you returned to the `Set` syntax. You need something that returns a `Date` type which `OpenRecordset` doesn't. Unfortunately I'm not able to help you there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're opening a recordset the variable should be a recordset.  You then reference the field in the table you're after in the messagebox.

If you have more than one record in the table it will return the first value - so either create a temporary query to return the value you're after, or search the recordset and go to the correct record.

```
Private Sub Test()
    Dim RS As dao.Recordset
    Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblDate")
    MsgBox "The month and year are: " & Format(RS.Fields("MyDateField"), "yyyy-mm")
End Sub
```

**Edit:**
If you're using a query to get the record:

```
Private Sub Test2()
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", "SELECT MAX(MyDateField) AS MaxDateField FROM tblDate")
    Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset
    MsgBox "The month and year are: " & Format(rs.Fields("MaxDateField"), "yyyy-mm")
End Sub
```

Comment: Setting the Dim to dao.Recordset fixed it up. Thank you for you quick response and help!

Answer (score 1):

In VBA, `Set` is only to be used when assigning to *object* variables. A variable of type `Date` is not an object variable, so you just say

```
RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblDate")
```

(note that you *can*, if you really want to, put a `Let` in front, but pretty much no one ever does).

Comment: When I remove Set I then get another error. Compile Error: Type Mismatch.